# Why are there no cross-platform mobile applications?

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile, cross-platform

As a part of my master's thesis, I am carrying a research topic on why there are no cross platform mobile applications.

As applications developed in Java can run on any operating system using the JVM, I was wondering why there is no interpreter like JVM for mobile devices through which one application can run under various mobile operating systems like Android, iOS, Windows, etc.

Any help or resources will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because the mobile OS vendors don't want you to be able to install programming language runtimes they aren't explicitly supporting, and don't care about making cross-platform apps easier than they already are?

Comment: There *are* cross-platform mobile applications.  They're written in HTML5, Javascript and CSS3.  There are also [platforms that allow you to write cross-platform apps natively.](http://appindex.com/blog/ten-best-cross-platform-development-mobile-enterprises/).  See also [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: Look at Google buried in lawsuits because of its JVM-like machine in Android. From technical side, I don't know why it shouldn't in theory be possible to create a Java equivalent of Xamarin (C#).

Comment: @kamilk: Xamarin [will run on Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/) already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ..and iOS and Windows.

Comment: @kamilk: Yep.  That's called "cross-platform,"  and it already works. No need for Java.

Comment: "why there are no cross platform mobile applications" can you define what you think this means? From my experience this is very much not the case today. Perhaps you specifically interested in running the same binary on multiple platforms rather than compiling for multiple targets (if so why do you think that matters)?

Answer (score 9):

As the co-founder of [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which does pretty much that I can answer that pretty easily.

You can cross compile (which is what we do) but you can't have a single binary that will work everywhere because mobile OS vendors don't allow it.

Apple doesn't allow JIT's and limits interpreters. All mobile devices  include app isolation which prevents a global JVM from servicing other applications.

Android can't do a "proper" portable JVM because of licensing and interest conflicts with Sun/Oracle.